# Como sumar la columna secundaria en una matriz?

Tags: java

me podrían ayudar? estoy empezando a aprender sobre las matrices y necesito calcular la suma de la diagonal secundaria. recién llevo la suma de la diagonal principal pero ya se me dificulto con la segunda.
esto es la parte del código que hice para la primera diagonal, si funciona. ya solamente falta la segunda.

```
float sumaDiagon1=0;
        col=0;
        for(ren=0;ren<5;ren++){
        sumaDiagon1+=matriz[ren][col];
        col++;
        }
        System.out.println("La suma de la diagonal principal es:"+sumaDiagon1);
```

me podrían ayudar por favor?
java

Comment: Piénsalo y dibújalo _en papel_: ¿cómo obtendrías la diagonal secundaria?